# Laravel Validation passing array rule for empty string

Tags: laravel

This passes validation

```php
$validated = validator(
    [
        "data" => ""
    ],
    [
        "data" => "array"
    ]
)->validate();
```

This doesn't (as expected)

```php
$validated = validator(
    [
        "data" => null
    ],
    [
        "data" => "array"
    ]
)->validate();
```

Is this a bug or expected behaviour?

Comment: what laravel version is this?

Comment: Tested on Laravel `9.50.2` `10.43.0` and `11.x-dev`.

Comment: you should follow what they [say](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#rule-array). "In general, you should always specify the array keys that are allowed to be present within your array."

Comment: @francisco array keys are sometimes integers and can be an undefined amount. string keys can sometimes also be optional

Comment: you can try to do like this:
`"data" => "array|nullable", "data.*" => "nullable", "data.*.field1" => "nullable"`

data is array or nullable, the key are nullable, the fields are nullable too.

Comment: It still allows a string to go through.

Comment: if u send this `""`, on `$request->data` it will be `null`.

Comment: so array validation is only supposed to work dependant on middleware? in my case the data isn't from a request which is why I was using the validator and not a form request

Comment: Right in the [beginning](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#introduction) "Laravel provides several different approaches to validate your application's incoming data." making it a form request, like this `$request = new Request($data);` won't work too. just do some PHP validations.

Answer (score 0):

It is by (controversial) design. Laravel validators are depended on TrimStrings and ConvertEmptyStringsToNull middleware that will prepare data for validation.

you can add required rule:

```
    $validated = validator(
        [
            "data" => ""
        ],
        [
            "data" => ['required', 'array']
        ]
    )->validate();
```

Comment: i cant add required when the data isn't required, the example is an over simplified version of what i actually have. i found that `sometimes|required|array` works. but if i add a rule `array` i would expect the data to be an array...